# EF Core Unlink / Detach Related Entity - One to Many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to unlink my entity's relation to another entity (Task).

But my entity's relation is still remains in TaskID column.

How can I delete this TaskID value?

*I am using entity framework core 2.2*

1. setting task null:
   [image: 1. setting task null]
2. task relation still remains
   [image: 2. task relation still remains]

   WorkHour workHourRecentCreated = workHourRepo.Get(workHourDb.ID);
   workHourRecentCreated.Task = null;
   workHourRepo.Edit(workHourRecentCreated);
   workHourRepo.Save();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to eager load the task in order for the change tracker to pick up the change.

If you have a taskID field,  setting that to null should update the database properly.

Comment: TaskID field created automatically by ef core, in my entity this column stands as model;
public Task Task { get; set; }

Comment: Ok gotcha.  Can you share the implement of your repository Get() method?   You might need to eager load the task in order for the change tracker to pick up the change.

Comment: Thank you ! it was because related entity (task) not loaded.